# How to securely deliver OSX in app purchases without going back to a server

Tags: in-app-purchase, mac-app-store

We have just recently added an app purchases to our OSX app, basically the in app purchase unlocks some hidden functionality in the app and is non-consumable. After posting on Stackoverflow and reading through documentation, we decided to implement a built in product model using the user preferences, similar to what is described here in Apple's documentaiton:

> After a product is successfully purchased, your application must unlock the feature and deliver it to the user. The simplest way to unlock features is by changing your application preferences. See “Implementing Application Preferences”. Application preferences are backed up when users backs up their iOS-based devices. Your application may want to recommend to users that they back up their devices after making a purchase to ensure that purchases are not lost.

We went with this model because it is a key requirement that our application should work without having to be connected to the internet every time the user wants to use the application so using a server product model was unacceptable. The downside of this is that it would be very easy to crack our app by simply adding the appropriate property to our app's preference plist file. Is there some middle ground that is less easy to crack but also allows for the user to use the in app purchased content without having to be connected to the inter? Apple's documentation did not seem to provide such a solution.

Comment: How are they going to pay you if they aren't connected to the internet?

Comment: @danielbeard Sorry if I wasn't clear in my original post. The user would need to be connected to the internet to purchase the upgrade but they shouldn't have to be connected to the internet every time they want to use the purchased content. I.E. use case: I download the app, I complete in app purchase right before boarding airplane, "Oh damn no WIFI on the plane!", I want to still be able to use my in app purchased content!